# Edit data on 3rd level mongo

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I can't find a way to edit nested data more than on 2nd level.
I have next model structure:

```
var Category = new Schema({
    name: String,
    url: String,
    id: String
});

var Subgroup = new Schema({
    name: String,
    url: String,
    id: String,
    categories: [Category]
});

var Group = new Schema({
    name: String,
    url: { type: String, default: '' },
    subgroups: [Subgroup]
});

module.exports = mongoose.model('group', Group);
```

I need to edit certain Category through the Group model. I tried all possible variations of working with nested arrays but have no result.

```
Group.findOneAndUpdate({
    _id: req.params.groupId,
    "subgroups.categories._id": req.params.categoryId
}, {
    $set: { 
        "subgroups.categories.$.name": attributes.name 
    }
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Wait, if you have the categoryId, `req.params.categoryId`, then you could just do the update like this:

```
Category.findOneAndUpdate({
    _id: req.params.categoryId
}, {$set: {name: attributes.name}})
```

But to solve the underlying question with updating nested objects, I would suggest you change your Schemas a bit if this is the type of actions you want to perform. Instead of saving arrays you can store the relationship to the parent in the nested object like this:

```
var Group = new Schema({
    name: String,
    url: {type: String, default: ''},
})
mongoose.model('Group', Group)

var Subgroup = new Schema({
    group: {type: ObjectId, ref: 'Group'},
    name: String,
    url: String,
    id: String,
})
mongoose.model('Subgroup', Subgroup)

var Category = new Schema({
    subgroup: {type: ObjectId, ref: 'Subgroup'},
    name: String,
    url: String,
    id: String
})
mongoose.model('Category', Category)
```

Now you can do the update by:

```
Category.findAndUpdate({
    subcategory: req.params.subcategoryId,
}, ...)
```

Or:

```
Subgroup.find({
    group: req.params.groupId,
}, function(err, subgroups) {
    subgroups.forEach(function(subgroup) {
        Category.findAndUpdate({
            subcategory: subgroup._id,
        }, ...)
    })
})
```